# Using @RequestBody and @ModelAttribute together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get at the body of a `POST`, and I'd like the parameters of my method to bind to an object.

Is this possible?

My current declaration doesn't ever get hit:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doStuff(@RequestBody byte[] bodyData, @ModelAttribute Form form, Model model ) {
```

Looks like I'm getting this exception:

```
- 2011-02-25 16:57:30,354 - ERROR - http-8080-3 - org.springframework.web.portle
t.DispatcherPortlet - Could not complete request
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: @RequestBody not supported
```

Comment: Do you have your @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations in place?

Comment: Is it that you are trying to get the POST body in the @RequestBody variable, and the GET parameters in the @ModelAttribute variable?

Comment: it that should be two method ? I just felt that you did something wrong by put the GET & POST in the same place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to work correctly, you have to be sure you're using [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html). This overrides [HandlerMethodInvoker's](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/support/HandlerMethodInvoker.html) [createHttpInputMessage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/support/HandlerMethodInvoker.html#createHttpInputMessage%28org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest%29) (which is throwing the exception you're seeing). (It does this in a private class.)

I believe you can just include the following in your *-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

WARNING: The below answer is for the case of needing @RequestBody and @RequestParam in the same handler method. It does not answer this question, but could be of use to someone.

I've tested this out using Spring 3.0.1. This is possible, but it's somewhat precarious. You MUST have your @RequestBody method argument before your @RequestParam argument. I'm guessing this is because [HandlerMethodInvoker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/support/HandlerMethodInvoker.html) reads the request body (along with the GET parameters) when retrieving parameters (and the request body can only be read once).

Here's an example (WARNING: I code in Scala, so I've not compiled this Java code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(
        @RequestBody String body,
        @RequestParam("param1") String parma1,
        Map<Object, Object> model: Map[AnyRef, AnyRef])
{
    model.put("test", test)
    model.put("body", body)

    return "Layout"
}
```

An alternative is to use @PathVariable. I've confirmed that this works.

Comment: As I read this I notice I didn't add in semi-colons. I'm not going to edit this to show how much I love not typing them in Scala :)

Comment: I bet I don't have that definition in my configuration. I'll test this out later to confirm. I'm using Groovy for a good bit of my code, so I'm also a fan of the no-semicolon :P. I don't see how it could work in Scala and not in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is kind of impossible. If you are using portlet version of Spring MVC (and it looks like from the logs) then you might be interested in [this JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7344).

AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter uses PortletHandlerMethodInvoker internally and the second is a inner subclass of HandlerMethodInvoker - the place where you can configure HttpMessageConverter-s. But they're set to null. And the property is final.

That even would be to workaround if you could substitute HandlerMethodInvoker, but you can not.. it's constructor-created ;)

One thing to notice is that Servlet version of Spring MVC fully supports HttpMessageConverter-s and does not suffer this issue.